# Where to get specific Visual Studio older versions?

Tags: c++, ide, compiler

I am reverse-engineering a piece of software. I have identified the compiler used as Microsoft Visual C/C++(2003), Microsoft Linker(7.10)[EXE32] - That is Visual Studio .NET 2003 version 7.1 .

I would like to build my code with this exact compiler in order to examine the resultant assembly, but the problem is that it is not available from microsoft anymore and I'm searching for a 3rd party archive of older versions of VS.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending software that meets specific requirements – not about recommending download links for specific software, so your question is not on-topic for this site. Unfortunately, I neither can tell where it would fit.